# Group lookup using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient 2.1.1

Tags: active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

#### Issue

I'm encountering a null reference exception when looking up a group by `MailNickname`. Note, *the nickname in question does not exist* in Active Directory, however, I would expect the library to handle this gracefully and not result in a null reference exception.

It's also worth noting, I am able to use the same code to lookup groups which do exist in Active Directory. I do not control the nicknames my code operate over since they're user input. I would simply like to lookup the group's info, or move on in the case the group does not exist.

#### Code

```
// Using nuget package Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient 2.1.1
//
await graphClient.Groups
    .Where( g => g.MailNickname == "FakeGroupNickname" )
    .ExecuteSingleAsync();
```

#### Exception

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.ReadOnlyQueryableSet2.&lt;&lt;ExecuteSingleAsync&gt;b__5&gt;d__7.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
  at Program.GroupMembershipHandler.<GetGroupIds>d__17.MoveNext()
```

#### Question

Is there another way of using the graph client library to query a group by `MailNickname` which will not result in a null reference exception when the group does not exist?

Aside, I'd love to know where to file a bug on this library. Null reference exceptions should never be thrown in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there another way of using the graph client library to query a group by MailNickname which will not result in a null reference exception when the group does not exist?

AFAIK , currently we should use try catch statement to handle the null reference exception and send error message like "MailNickname doesn't exist" to user . Or you need to filter on the results (groups collection) returned . Any feedback , you could post to [Azure AD Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) .

Comment: Thanks for the info. Null reference exception could be caused by any bug, however, and not indicate "MailNickname doesn't exist" accurately. I've given the feedback on the forum you provided at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/31606639-return-null-when-group-cannot-be-found-by-mailnick